# Pronomen "es" in Verbindung mit Substantiven (maskulin/feminin)?

Tags: grammar

Ist es richtig, wenn man einen Satz wie *"**Es** ist ein roter Apfel."* verwendet?

Schon länger benutze ich die Sprache täglich und würde dieses Pronomen anstatt **"er"** benutzen, wenn ich mich schnell für etwas entscheiden müsste, z.B. beim Sprechen.

Meine Frage ist, ob man **"es"** in solche Situationen verwenden kann oder ob das Pronommen immer mit dem Genus des Substantivs übereinstimmen sollte? (in dem Fall oben maskulin)

Ich vermute, dass das Pronomen **"es"** in solchen Situationen eher etwas wie **"das"** bedeutet, habe allerdings keine Ahnung, ob so eine Aussage überhaupt Sinn macht.

Comment: *Er ist ein Mann* und *Sie ist eine Frau*, aber *Beim Täter handelt **es** sich um einen Mann* bzw. *handelt **es** sich um eine Frau*. Und um die Sache jetzt ganz zu verkomplizieren: *Sie ist ein Mädchen.* (obwohl *das Mädchen*).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ich denke, [dieser Artikel auf canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-es.html) beantwortet die Frage sehr umfassend.

Die für deine Frage relevanten Informationen möchte ich kurz zitieren:

> ***es* als Fürwort**
>
> Das Personalpronomen *es* steht stellvertretend für ein Nomen oder ein Adjektiv als Prädikativ (mit *sein*, *werden* usw.)
>
> Als Prädikativ kann *es* sich auch auf nicht sächliche, nicht im Singular stehende Nomen oder auf ein Adjektiv beziehen. Das Verb richtet sich nach dem Subjekt, nicht nach *es*:
>
> > Sie ist Ärztin und ihre Tochter wird es auch. [Anm. von mir: Der Arzt bzw. die Ärztin]
>
> Das Personalpronomen *es* steht stellvertretend für ein Nomen als Subjekt in einem Gleichsetzungsatz (mit *sein*)
>
> In einem Gleichsetzungssatz (mit *sein*) kann *es* sich auch auf nicht sächliche, nicht im Singular stehende Nomen beziehen. Das Verb richtet sich nach dem Prädikativ, nicht nach *es*:
>
> > Drei Männer betraten das Lokal. Es waren Polizisten.
>
> ***es* als formales Subjekt bei Gleichsetzung mit *sein***
>
> Das Pronomen *es* kann sich in einem Gleichsetzungsatz (in der Regel mit *sein*) als unpersönliches Subjekt (oder Prädikativ) auf nicht sächliche, nicht im Singular stehende Nomen beziehen:
>
> > Jemand kam hinein. Es war mein Vater.
> >
> > Meine Mutter war es, die hereinkam.
>
> Das Verb richtet sich nicht nach es, sondern nach dem Bezugswort.
>
> > Es war meine Mutter.
> >
> > Es waren meine Eltern.
>
> In dieser Funktion kann es nicht weggelassen werden. Es kann häufig durch das stärkere *das* ersetzt werden, welches in ähnlicher Weise verwendet wird.